# Repetative capturing group matches only last occurence

Tags: java, regex, backtracking, capturing-group

Following text data given i am experiencing strange capturing group behavior.
When i try to iterate over all tables only the last row of data. Is there a way to maintain all capturing groups not only the last row (values of each table)?

I am using this pattern `(?<tabname>\S+)\n\=*\n(?:(\d+)\ *\|\ *(\d+)\n)+`

```
TABLE1
=======
1  | 2
15 | 2
3  | 15

TABLE2
=======
3  | 5
12 | 2
17 | 7
```

---

**Edit**: Sorry for my inconsistent question, here my expected and actual outputs:

**Expected** output would be:

**Match 1 of 2:**

```
Group "tabname":    TABLE1
Group 2:    1
Group 3:    2
Group 4:    15
Group 5:    2
Group 6:    3
Group 7:    15
```

**Match 2 of 2:**

```
Group "tabname":    TABLE2
Group 2:    3
Group 3:    5
Group 4:    12
Group 5:    2
Group 6:    17
Group 7:    7
```

But **actual** output is:

**Match 1 of 2:**

```
Group "tabname":    TABLE1
Group 2:    3
Group 3:    15
```

**Match 2 of 2:**

```
Group "tabname":    TABLE1
Group 2:    17
Group 3:    7
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor/language? Did you mean you have something like [`(?<tabname>\S+)\n\S*\n(?:(\d+)\s*\|\s*(\d+)(?:$|\n))*`](https://regex101.com/r/zY6pS1/2)? Note that in Java, repeated capture groups always are re-written, and the last one is only kept.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Java

Comment: what are you trying to capture?

Comment: @rock321987 Tablename with all the data as numbered capturing groups

Comment: *with all the data as numbered capturing groups* - could you please add the exact expected output to the question, please?

Comment: if I am correct, you can use **[(?s)(?:(TABLE\d+)|\G)(?:(?!TABLE).)+?(\d+)\s+\|\s+(\d+)](https://regex101.com/r/aR6wR7/2)**

Comment: all groups cannot be numbered separately until it is known the number of groups beforehand

Comment: @rock321987: With multiple blocks of text, `\G` is not a nice solution (though some programming logic could help). Calaedo, what if Result 1 is `[TABLE1, 1, 2, 15, 2, 3, 15]` as an array of strings?

Comment: @calaedo: *why should the number of groups should be known before?* - see my first comment, you would need to explicitly add capturing groups in the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would not mind, as long as the tablename is in the same array (Needed for unit based batch processing)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you guide me the problem I may face??I am fairly new in using `\G` and still trying to understand it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect your data in 2 passes. The first regex will just match the tables with all the values:

```
"(?<tabledata>\\S+)\\s+\\S+(?<vals>[|\\d\\s]+)"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS5tJ7/1). Next, we'll just match the numbers and add them to the string array (with the simple `\d+` regex).

Here is a [full Java demo](http://ideone.com/bKWqYL) producing `[[TABLE1, 1, 2, 15, 2, 3, 15], [TABLE2, 3, 5, 12, 2, 17, 7]]`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "TABLE1\n=======\n1  | 2\n15 | 2\n3  | 15\n\nTABLE2\n=======\n3  | 5\n12 | 2\n17 | 7"; 
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<tabledata>\\S+)\\s+\\S+(?<vals>[|\\d\\s]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()){
            List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
            if (matcher.group("tabledata") != null) {
                lst.add(matcher.group("tabledata"));
            }
            if (matcher.group("vals") != null) {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(matcher.group("vals"));
                while (m.find()) {
                    lst.add(m.group(0));
                }
            }
            res.add(lst);
        } 
        System.out.println(res); 
    }
}
```

Comment: haha..that's how I used to think before I read(a bit) about `\G`..i know you don't want to complicate things..+1

Comment: @rock321987: `\G` based solution of yours is also valid. Just unroll the tempered greedy quantifier (see [how it can be done here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970))

Comment: Just `(?:(TABLE\d++)|\G)[^T\d]*+(?:T(?!ABLE\d)[^T\d]*+)*(\d+)` should be enough. Java also supports possessive quantifiers.

Comment: The point is in using negated character classes (with a negative lookeahead in most cases) so that all the subsequent subpatterns could not match the same character at the same location. Some unrolled patterns can be just used with the help of smart grouping and quantifiers.

Comment: seems like I have a lot to read today..will read when reach home and ask if there is a problem..thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use this regex

```
(?s)(?:(TABLE\d+)|\G)(?:(?!TABLE).)+?(\d+)\s+\|\s+(\d+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR6wR7/2)**

With a bit of Java help, you can achieve the result

```
String line = "TABLE1\n=======\n1  | 2\n15 | 2\n3  | 15\n\nTABLE2\n=======\n3  | 5\n12 | 2\n17 | 7";
String pattern = "(?s)(?:(TABLE\\d+)|\\G)(?:(?!TABLE).)+?(\\d+)\\s+\\|\\s+(\\d+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
int flag = 0;

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        flag = 0;
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + "\n" + m.group(2) + "\n" + m.group(3));
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println(m.group(2) + "\n" + m.group(3)); 
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/NeXAzG)**

Comment: Just FYI: a tempered greedy token is very resource-consuming, and Java regex engine is prone to stack overflow issue with complex patterns (even short ones, but with quantified alternation groups). Yes, the code looks cleaner, but you would still need to declare the arrays/lists for the results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the info..still working on my regex